# CodeBlocks is not building properly

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am trying to learn how to program in the c++ language and I have downloaded Code::Blocks as advice from an online tutorial, when creating a new project on Code::Blocks and selecting a console application it opens with a small program that should say "hello world" when I try to build and run this program it says "this project is not built yet, would you like to build it?" I select yes and absolutely nothing happens. On the build log it says 0 errors and when I click build and run again it says its not built! I have no clue what to do or what is wrong, can anybody help?

Comment: I suspect that you don't have a compiler... BTW you should state version of Code::Blocks you use.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?Could you approve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a compiler or you haven't configured CodeBlocks with a compiler.To fix it:
Download and Install a C/C++  compiler for your OS and configure CodeBlocks to use it. Or if you are using Windows you can also download [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe) CodeBlocks setup which already includes MinGW compiler.

Comment: I already downloaded the CodeBlocks set up with the MinGW compiler but just to be sure I completely deleted it and then downloaded the one from your link, I still have the exact same problem but this time it popped up with a message when I opened CodeBlocks; it says "can't find compiler executable in your configured search path for GNU GCC compiler" so I'm guessing there is something wrong with the path for some reason and CodeBlocks can not find the compiler?? and how do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: After so much time I expect you solved this. But just installing MinGW package manager is not enough.
After that you have to select basic setup from the left list and mark all elements on the right list.
Once selected, go to Installation -> Apply Changes.
This will download GCC compiler.
Note that  default configuration for codeblocks reads from c:\MinGW directory. That is the default installation directory. Remember if you changed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact same issues. You just need to create a project/C++ source file instead of the empty file.